# Validate <paper-input> value on-change instead of on-key?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I've got a simple `<paper-input>` element.
I'm using its pattern-attribute to validate it. It always validates when I enter a key (`on-key`). Instead I would like it to validate `on-change`

```
<paper-input error-message="Not a number"
             label="Enter a number"  
             pattern="\d*" 
             errorMessage="Not a number" 
             auto-validate></paper-input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the auto-validate attribute, and add an on-value-changed event listener that runs the paper-inputs [validate function](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#validate)

here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/jucusor/edit?html) on jsbin

```
<paper-input id='input' error-message="Not a number" label="Enter a number" pattern="\d*" errorMessage="Not a number"></paper-input>

<script>
  document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('value-changed', function(e) {
    // console.log(e.detail.value);
    e.currentTarget.validate();
  })
</script>
```